# PHP regex any number

Tags: php, regex

I search for patterns like this number+space+number+space+anything

If have this right now:

```
if( preg_match( '[0-9][ ][0-9][ ].', $searchString ) )
```

This seems to work ok but fails on the numbers. As far as i can see there should be a selector for "any number". How can i do this in regex.

It should return true for these cases:

```
0 0 asdf
1 0 asdf
0 30 adsf asdf
22 0 a
...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[0-9]` only accepts the integers 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9. For any integer, you need to allow one or more repetitions of `[0-9]`. If you use the shortcut `\d` for `[0-9]` then you can write it as

`\d+ \d+ .*`

The `+` symbol means **One or more repetitions**.

Note: 
It seems like your new to reg expression. Try out this [free regex tutorial](https://regexone.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the tut ;) I definetly give it a try

Answer (score 3):

I'm kind of surprised that works seeing that you should have your regex between //. But that aside, you should realise that your `[0-9]` is only looking for a MANDATORY ONE INSTANCE of a digit.

Changing that to `[0-9]+` should fix your issue, though I think studying a bit of regex first will help you in the long run.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ;) it very straightforward ... it should be possible to mark multiple answers as accepted ._.

Comment: hehe, no problems. Just feel free to mark whoever you think has the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

Change your regexp pattern as shown below:

```
$re = "/\d+? \d+? .*$/";

var_dump(preg_match($re, "0 30 adsf asdf"));  // 1
var_dump(preg_match($re, "22 0 a"));          // 1
```

**Details**:

- `\d+?` - should match at least one number
- `.*$`  - matches any character at the end of the string

Comment: Thanks for that answer. Tested this and it works just fine. Its seems like there are many ways in regex to catch a pattern like this. As mentioned in the other comment it should be possible to mark multple answers as accepted/correct