# How can I apply a style to verse numbers in a scripture passage contained in a string via php?

Tags: php, html

I need to find a way to identify the verse numbers in a scripture passage so that I can apply a style to them (ie color and superscript). I am using php and pulling the passages in from a MySQL database. Below is a small code snippet that I am using on an about us page.

```
<span>What is your favorite passage in the bible? </span><?php echo $row[ "verse" ]; ?><br><?php echo $row[ "scripture" ]; ?>
```

`verse` contains something like `Jeremiah 22:15-16` and `scripture` contains something like

> 15But a beautiful cedar palace does not make a great king! Your
>   father, Josiah, also had plenty to eat and drink. But he was just and
>   right in all his dealings. That is why God blessed him. 16He gave
>   justice and help to the poor and needy, and everything went well for
>   him. Isn’t that what it means to know me?” says the Lord.

I want to be able to analyze any string and apply a `<span class="verse">` in front of the verse number and `</span>` after it before it echoes the string to the page. This way the output can look something more along the lines of this:

> **15**But a beautiful cedar palace does not make a great king! Your father, Josiah, also had plenty to eat and drink. But he was just and right in all his dealings. That is why God blessed him. **16**He gave justice and help to the poor and needy, and everything went well for him. Isn’t that what it means to know me?” says the Lord.

```
<span class="verse">15</span>But a beautiful cedar palace does not make a great king! Your father, Josiah, also had plenty to eat and drink. But he was just and right in all his dealings. That is why God blessed him. <span class="verse">16</span>He gave justice and help to the poor and needy, and everything went well for him. Isn’t that what it means to know me?” says the Lord.
```

I haven't been able to find a solution online. I can find how to search for a certain character or substring in a string, but not how to find any number within a string. I greatly appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: you need to search for a regex that get you the numbers and replace them with span+number

Comment: Why does `John 3:16` contain `15But a beautiful`... Shouldn't a separate verse's scripture contain that? I assume you have a one-to-one relationship between verse and scripture in that regard? Really it seems like your best bet would be to structure your data so that each `scripture` only contains the *individual* verse's scripture.

Comment: you can start from here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39263061/8620333

Comment: @ObsidianAge I apologize for not changing that. I started this post with John 3:16 as an example but then decided that I wanted to include a passage with multiple verses to show that I want all verse numbers to get the formatting. I will edit the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @TemaniAfif for steering me in the right direction I was able to find a solution to this. Using `preg_match_all()` to search a string for a pattern allowed me to locate the verse numbers in the string and replace them with  before and  after each verse number. The `preg_match_all()` function matches all occurrences of pattern in string.

After performing my sql query I ran the following code:

```
<?php
while ( $row = $query->fetch_assoc() ) {
        $pattern = "/\d+/";
        $passage = $row[ "scripture" ];
        preg_match_all( $pattern, $passage, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER );
        foreach ( $matches[0] as $match ) {
            $passage = str_replace( $match, "<sup class='verse'>" . $match . "</sup>", $passage );
        }
    ?>
    <p>
        <span><?php echo $row[ "verse" ]; ?></span><br><?php echo $passage; ?><br>
    </p>
<?php } ?>
```

`$pattern` defines the string(s) that we are trying to find within the string. In this case, `/\d+/` matches any number of any size within the string. It can be one or more digits. If we only wanted to match 1 digit verses we would remove the `+`.

`$passage` is simply the input string that we are searching in. In this case it is a row from a SQL table.

`$matches` is the name of the multi-dimensional array that preg_match_all() will return any matches to that it discovers.

`PREG_PATTERN_ORDER` is a flag and actually doesn't need to be there as it is the default option. `PREG_PATTERN_ORDER` orders results so that `$matches[0]` is an array of full pattern matches, `$matches[1]` is an array of strings matched by the first parenthesized subpattern, and so on.

Because we only care about the pattern matches, we then cycle through them with a `foreach()` by accessing the $matches[0] array. While in the `foreach()` we replace the matches in our string by placing `<sup class='verse'>` before and `</sup>` after each match using `str_replace()`.

The first parameter of `str_replace()` is our match. The second is what we are going to replace the match with. The last parameter is the subject, in our case the string.

I hope this helps anyone else trying to accomplish the same thing or something similar.

[php.net preg_match_all() documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)
[php.net str_replace() documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)